# Problem when merging two elements with subdivision surface modifier

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I'm having a problem merging two elements with a subdivision surface modifier. The vertices are pretty well aligned, I think it has something to do with the subdivision surface modifier but I can't figure it out.

To be sure I was doing it the right way I hid everything but the two edge loops I want to merge and then aligned all the vertices one by one to have an exact copy. Everything looks good if I have the viewport on 0. The higher it goes the worse it gets. I don't know what to do to fix it.

I also tried to smooth it with the smooth tool but that didn't work either.

To be more expecific if I don't have the subdivision surface modifier everything looks just fine.

Thanks in advance.
[image][image]

Comment: maybe flipped normals, or inner faces, or edges overlapping...

Comment: Thanks for the answer moonbot. That can't happen if the edge loops are copy of each other I think(kinda new to blender). I also tried to recalculate the vertices but that did not help either. Its weird because the subdivision surface modifier fucks the vertices up. It's like the materials of the two elements are different or something like that, not sure tbh. Look the color of the two elements it's different https://imgur.com/IXe4OS5

Comment: If you can, post your .blend file so that users here can experiment and find out what the problem is.

Comment: Sure I can, here is the file, thanks for your time. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=DGDG9xn3" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/DGDG9xn3/)

Comment: your normals are flipped, select all in Edit mode and press shift N

Comment: holy shit thank you so much. How did that happen? I would like to know how to avoid that in a future, Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Your normals are flipped, select all in *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.